# NOT NULL constraint failed: with my create function

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to have one view that produces 2 forms and saves them both with one button. I have a good idea on how to accomplish this in an update view so I'm trying to apply the same logic with a create view. Everything seems to be working ok but I'm getting a NOT NUlL constraint failed error. I realize that this error has something to do with my second form probably not being able to find the "carrier" to attach itself too, I just don't know how to go about solving it.

Here's my code:

MODELS.PY

```
class Carrier(models.Model):
    carrier_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    mc_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=True)
    dot_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True)
    carrier_ein = models.CharField(max_length=9, unique=True)
    carrier_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    carrier_phone_two = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    carrier_phone_three = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    carrier_fax = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    carrier_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    US_STATES_OR_CAN_PROVINCES = (
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
        ('AS', 'American Samoa'),
        ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
        ('CA', 'California'),
        ('CO', 'Colorado'),
        ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
        ('DC', 'District of Columbia'),
        ('DE', 'Delaware'),
        ('FL', 'Florida'),
        ('GA', 'Georgia'),
        ('GU', 'Guam'),
        ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
        ('IA', 'Iowa'),
        ('ID', 'Idaho'),
        ('IL', 'Illinois'),
        ('IN', 'Indiana'),
        ('KS', 'Kansas'),
        ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
        ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
        ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
        ('MD', 'Maryland'),
        ('ME', 'Maine'),
        ('MI', 'Michigan'),
        ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
        ('MO', 'Missouri'),
        ('MP', 'Northern Mariana Islands'),
        ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
        ('MT', 'Montana'),
        ('NA', 'National'),
        ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
        ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
        ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
        ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
        ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
        ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
        ('NV', 'Nevada'),
        ('NY', 'New York'),
        ('OH', 'Ohio'),
        ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
        ('OR', 'Oregon'),
        ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
        ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'),
        ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
        ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
        ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
        ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
        ('TX', 'Texas'),
        ('UT', 'Utah'),
        ('VA', 'Virginia'),
        ('VI', 'Virgin Islands'),
        ('VT', 'Vermont'),
        ('WA', 'Washington'),
        ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
        ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
        ('WY', 'Wyoming'),
        ('AB', 'Alberta'),
        ('BC','British Columbia'),
        ('MB', 'Manitoba'),
        ('NB', 'New Brunswick'),
        ('NL', 'Newfoundland and Labrador'),
        ('NT', 'Northwest Territories'),
        ('NS', 'Nova Scotia'),
        ('NU', 'Nunavut'),
        ('ON', 'Ontario'),
        ('PE', 'Prince Edward Island'),
        ('QC', 'Quebec'),
        ('SK', 'Saskatchewan'),
        ('YT', 'Yukon')
    )
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('USA', 'United States'),
        ('CAN', 'Canada')
    )
    carrier_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    carrier_state_prov = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                            choices=US_STATES_OR_CAN_PROVINCES)
    carrier_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    carrier_country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES)
    carrier_notes = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.carrier_name

class CarrierDocuments(models.Model):
    carrier = models.OneToOneField(Carrier, related_name='carrier_documents',
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    broker_carrier_agreement = models.FileField(
                                upload_to='broker_carrier_agreement/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    carrier_w9 = models.FileField(upload_to='w9/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    insurance = models.FileField(upload_to='insurance/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    payment_instructions = models.FileField(upload_to='pay_instructions/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def create_carrier(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        carrier_form = CarrierCreateForm(request.POST)
        carrier_documents = CarrierDocumentsUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if carrier_form.is_valid() and carrier_documents.is_valid():
            carrier_form.save()
            carrier_documents.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Carrier created!'))
            return redirect('carriers:all')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        carrier_form = CarrierCreateForm()
        carrier_documents = CarrierDocumentsUpload()
    return render(request, 'carriers/create_carrier.html', {
        'carrier_form': carrier_form,
        'carrier_documents': carrier_documents,
    })
```

FORMS.PY

```
class CarrierCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Carrier
        fields = ['carrier_name', 'mc_number', 'dot_number', 'carrier_ein',
                'carrier_phone', 'carrier_phone_two', 'carrier_phone_three',
                'carrier_fax', 'carrier_email', 'carrier_city', 'carrier_state_prov',
                'carrier_zipcode', 'carrier_country','carrier_notes']

class CarrierDocumentsUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CarrierDocuments
        fields = ['broker_carrier_agreement', 'carrier_w9', 'insurance',
                'payment_instructions']
```

I'm thinking that within my view, i'm basically just submitting both forms simultaneously without actually connecting them. Based on my research something like this should work. But I'm still getting the contstraint error.

```
if carrier_form.is_valid() and carrier_documents.is_valid():
    carrier = carrier_form(commit=False)
    carrier_documents.save()
    carrier_documents.carrier = carrier
    carrier.save()
    messages.success(request, ('Carrier created!'))
    return redirect('carriers:all')
```

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you,

**Update per the answer below**

This one does save my "carrier" and my uploaded documents to the right place but i'm still getting the contstraint error.

```
def create_carrier(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        carrier_form = CarrierCreateForm(request.POST)
        carrier_documents = CarrierDocumentsUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if carrier_form.is_valid() and carrier_documents.is_valid():
            carrier = carrier_form.save(commit=False)
            carrier.save()
            carrier_documents.carrier = carrier
            carrier_documents.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Carrier created!'))
            return redirect('carriers:all')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        carrier_form = CarrierCreateForm()
        carrier_documents = CarrierDocumentsUpload()
    return render(request, 'carriers/create_carrier.html', {
        'carrier_form': carrier_form,
        'carrier_documents': carrier_documents,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_carrier(request):
    carrier_form = CarrierCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    carrier_documents = CarrierDocumentsUpload(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        if carrier_form.is_valid() and carrier_documents.is_valid():
           carrier = carrier_form.save(commit=False)
           carrier.save()
           carrier2=carrier_documents.save(commit=False)
           carrier2.carrier = carrier
           carrier2.save()
           messages.success(request, ('Carrier created!'))
           return redirect('carriers:all')
    return render(request, 'carriers/create_carrier.html', {
        'carrier_form': carrier_form,
        'carrier_documents': carrier_documents,
})
```

Try this one

Comment: Please edit your existing answer in response to feedback rather than adding a new one.

Comment: Edwin, Thank you for helping me on this! This latest answer did work. I guess my main problem was that I was calling the forms within my request.method == 'POST'.  This would probably work if I was creating a form to edit an existing "carrier" which i'll be coding next.

Answer (score 0):

```
if carrier_form.is_valid() and carrier_documents.is_valid():
carrier = carrier_form(commit=False)
carrier.save()
carrier_documents.carrier = carrier
carrier_documents.save()
messages.success(request, ('Carrier created!'))
return redirect('carriers:all')
```

Interchange the carrier and carrier_document save() method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this got me a bit closer I think but not quite fixed. I added my updated view to the bottom of the original post.

I will say this line gave me a an "object not callable error"
carrier = carrier_form(commit=False)